# Ensure High Availability of Datanodes in a HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, high-availability

I have a two master and three datanode HDFS cluster setup. They are AWS EC2 instances.

I have to test High Availability of Datanodes i.e., if during load run where data is written on HDFS, a datanode dies then there is no data loss. The two remaning 
datanodes which are alive should take care of the data writes.

I have set below properties in hdfs-site.xml.
`dfs.replication = 2` (because if any one datanode dies, then there is no issue of not able to meet replication factor)

```
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy = ALWAYS
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable = true
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.best-effort = true
```

My questions are:

1 - Does setting up above properties suffice my Datanode High Availability? Or something else is needed?
2 - On dfs service startup, I do see below INFO on namenode logs:

```
2017-06-27 10:51:52,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 2
2017-06-27 10:51:52,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2017-06-27 10:51:52,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2017-06-27 10:51:52,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
```

But I still see that the files being created on HDFS are with replication factor 3. Why is that so? This would hurt my High Availability of Datanodes.

```
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoopuser supergroup     247373 2017-06-29 09:36 /topics/testTopic/year=2017/month=06/day=29/hour=14/testTopic+210+0001557358+0001557452
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoopuser supergroup       1344 2017-06-29 08:33 /topics/testTopic/year=2017/month=06/day=29/hour=14/testTopic+228+0001432839+0001432850
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoopuser supergroup       3472 2017-06-29 09:03 /topics/testTopic/year=2017/month=06/day=29/hour=14/testTopic+228+0001432851+0001432881
-rw-r--r--   3 hadoopuser supergroup       2576 2017-06-29 08:33 /topics/testTopic/year=2017/month=06/day=29/hour=14/testTopic+23+0001236477+0001236499
```

P.S. - My records are written on HDFS by Confluent Kafka Connect HDFS Sink Connector.

Comment: Did you restart the cluster? Are you referring to existing files, or new ones? Do you set the replication factor within your code? I believe the answer lies within one of these questions. Otherwise check the connector's configurations.